# How can I resolve ViewAnimationUtils (cannot find symbol) error?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have problem with using animation in my app 
This is my code :

```
int cx = (search.getLeft() + search.getRight()) / 2;
                int cy = (search.getTop() + search.getBottom()) / 2;

// get the initial radius for the clipping circle
                int initialRadius = search.getWidth();

// create the animation (the final radius is zero)
                Animator anim =
                              ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(search, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);

// make the view invisible when the animation is done
                anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

When I want to use ViewAnimationUtils and error appears containing this message :

```
cannot find symbol
```

and also when I want to import this class in my project, I got same error 
Does anyone know how can I get rid of this message and resolve this problem.I use API 21 in my app. 
This is a part of my androidmanifest.xml code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:maxSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @jitendraparmar I already posted my codes. I have problem with importing ViewAnimationUtils in my project. In Google's website wrote this class available in API 21 and I set my program to compile with that API but it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and tried the same fix but it was only when I checked my projects's external libraries that I found I didn't have "Android API 21 Platform" inside.

Depending on your IDEA, you will have to go into the project settings and change the project sdk to 21.